# h:commandLink not working as intended

Tags: java, html, jsf

I have an problem which in turn is causing a lot of headaches. I need to dynamically create buttons/images which link to JSF actionListener. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<h:form>
  <div class="carousel-container">
    <div id="carousel">
      <h:outputText value="#{courseBean.course}" escape="false"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</h:form>
```

what courseBean.course gets is the Overriden toString which returns the following:

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    return "<div class=\"carousel-feature\"> "
            + "<h:commandLink id=\"" + courseID + "\" actionListener=\"#{courseBean.getCourseSelected}\">"
            + "<img class=\"carousel-image\" src=\"Images/testButton.jpg\"/>"
            + "<span style=\"display:bloack; position:absolute; top:20px; bottom:20px; left:0; right:0; "
            + "background:white; background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);\">" + courseName + "</span>"
            + "</h:commandLink> "
            + "<div class=\"carousel-caption\"> "
            + "</div>"
            + "</div>";
}//end method toString
```

The HTML is being rendered fine and image is being displayed in the carousel however when it is clicked actionListener is not being called which is the issue here.

edit: the actionListener only prints the courseID to the console nothing major.

Thank you for taking your time :)

Answer (score 0):

That approach is wrong, if you do "view source" you will see the `<h:commandLink` in the source of your page (because it wont be processed by JSF life cycle at all)  , while if you had a `<h:commandLink` in your xhtml page the generated html source will contain a `<a href....>` element

You better rethink of your original goal and ask a question on how to achieve it...